# Посчитать количество повторений елемента в базе

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть 4 таблицы

```
--------------------
STORAGE
--------------------
SCOPE    |  SCODE
---------|----------
MATERIAL | MATRLN001
GUIDELINE| GUINMK001
PROJECT  | PRJDCS001
MATERIAL | MATRLN002
PROJECT  | PRJDCS002
MATERIAL | MATRLN003
GUIDELINE| GUINMK002
PROJECT  | PRJDCS003
GUIDELINE| GUINMK003
MATERIAL | MATRLN004
PROJECT  | PRJDCS004

-----------------------
MATERIAL
-----------------------
CODE | SECCODE | TAGID
-----------------------
MAT  | RLN001  | 2
MAT  | RLN002  | 2
MAT  | RLN003  | 1
MAT  | RLN004  | 3

-----------------------
GUIDELINE
-----------------------
CODE | SECCODE | TAGID
-----------------------
GUI  | NMK001  | 3
GUI  | NMK002  | 2
GUI  | NMK003  | 1

-----------------------
PROJECT
-----------------------
CODE | SECCODE | TAGID
-----------------------
PRJ  | DCS001  | 3
PRJ  | DCS002  | 3
PRJ  | DCS003  | 2
PRJ  | DCS004  | 2
```

нужно вывести TAGID и количество его использований

Как то так:

```
-------------
RESULT
-------------
TAGID | COUNT
-------------
1     | 2
2     | 5
3     | 4
-------------
```

`SCODE` в `STORAGE` создается как `SCODE = CODE || CHR(9) || SECCODE`

Стал в тупик, не знаю как побороть и придумать запрос:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select TAGID,sum(cnt) cnt
  from (
    select TAGID,count(1) cnt from MATERIAL group by TAGID
     union all
    select TAGID,count(1) from GUIDELINE group by TAGID
     union all
    select TAGID,count(1) from PROJECT group by TAGID
  )
 group by TAGID
```

Если хотите можете конечно еще переклеить все это дело с STORAGE, но зачем она при подсчете количества в разрезе TAGID решительно не понятно. И структура базы с тремя таблицами с одинаковой структурой и неким составным полем в STORAGE мягко говоря странная...

Answer (score 0):

не оно?

```
SELECT TAGID, COUNT(TAGID) FROM PROJECT GROUP BY TAGID
```

Так то не понятен принцип подсчета, как эти 4 таблицы связаны и зачем они при подсчета тэгов